# Load a jsp page every 20 secs after 1st page load

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am trying to autosubmit a form upon 1st load and then refresh every 20 secs. I have tried below but it keeps loading the page all the time. is that correct implementation or how I can achieve that.

```
 window.onload=function(){
    var auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); }, 100);

    function submitform(){
      document.forms["frm1"].submit();
    }

    function autoRefresh(){
       clearTimeout(auto);
       auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 20000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `setInterval()` instead :

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    //Refresh code here
    //location.reload();
}, 20000);
```

So the code inside will be triggered every 20 second.

Comment: i have tried this.... it will wait for 20 sec and then load the page..... but i need to submit a page and load it immediately and then 20 sec interval. i am submitting this form document.forms["frm1"].submit();